Why am I getting NoClassDefFoundError for TokenExchangeOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider in Spring Security OAuth2?
I'm working on a Spring Boot application that uses Spring Security OAuth2 for authentication. However, I’m encountering an issue while creating the authorizedClientManagerRegistrar bean.
Here’s the full error stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'authorizedClientManagerRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerRegistrar]: Factory method 'authorizedClientManagerRegistrar' threw exception with message: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/TokenExchangeOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/TokenExchangeOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerRegistrar.<clinit>(OAuth2ClientConfiguration.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerConfiguration.authorizedClientManagerRegistrar(OAuth2ClientConfiguration.java:113)
    ... [other lines omitted for brevity]


What I've Tried:
I have added the following dependencies in my pom.xml to ensure OAuth2 is available:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    <version>6.3.3</version>
</dependency>


Spring Boot Version: 3.+
Spring Security Version: 6.3.3
JDK Version: 21.0.0

Remove the version tag from the dependency. Spring Boot will manage the correct (and compatible version). If you shoehorned more versions into your dependencies remove them, especially if they are org.springframework dependencies. If you want more detailed answers add your full pom.xml.

Hi @ M. Deinum, I am not directly using this dependency. It is being included as part of our custom starter

Well if that is the case don't upgrade. As it clearly isn't compatible.
